# Declaring and using PHP variables in views works fine in Localhost but not on live server (ubuntu AWS) Laravel 4.1

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services

I have honed my website to work fine on my localhost, but I am having trouble on my live server.  When I declare variables in my views, and try to use them, I am getting js or php errors (depending on where I declare and use the variable).  Here are the examples:

In js, I declare a php variable like so:

//in javascript

```
<? $id = Session::get('redirected_id'); ?>
@if(isset($id))
$('#myModal').modal('show');
@endif
```

Basically if I send a variable with the redirect to the view, I want this modal to appear.  When I run this on localhost, all of the js works fine.  When I run this on my live server, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

in reference to `<? $id = Session::get('redirected_id'); ?>`

On another note, I am getting php errors on my live server when I declare a variable in the html portion, and then use it as an "offset" variable.  For example:

```
<? $offset=0; ?>
@foreach($artists_near as $artist)

@if($offset%4==0 && $offset > 0)
<article class="MusicianCol clearfix fadeMusicBox" style="display:none;">
@endif
```

It is complaining at the line:

```
@if($offset%4==0 && $offset > 0)
```

saying:

```
Undefined variable: offset
```

This is strange because I am seeing no errors on the localhost.  I am using the same declarations for jquery, etc.. on the pages using the blade syntax, so I should be including the same files.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your production environment has the `short_open_tag` setting disabled. For full compatibility its recommended that you do not turn it on and instance use the full php tag `<?php` instead of `<?`